Covariant derivative with torsion
The covariant derivative is defined (on contravariant vectors) as:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu = \partial_\mu V^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu \rho} V^\rho  \tag{1}$$
The purpose of the covariant derivative is to construct a derivative which transforms as a genuine tensor. If there is no torsion actually I could also write:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu = \partial_\mu V^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{(\mu \rho)} V^\rho \tag{2}$$
However,  in case of non-zero torsion, what would be the appropiate covariant derivative ?
Would it be:
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu = \partial_\mu V^\nu + (\Gamma^\nu_{(\mu \rho)} + \Gamma^\nu_{[\mu \rho]}) V^\rho$$
which is actually as equation (1)
or instead
$$\nabla_\mu V^\nu = \partial_\mu V^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{(\mu \rho)} V^\rho \tag{2}$$
The question is of interest, since in order to make a derivative covariant one would only need a derivative like eq. (2), because  $\Gamma^\nu_{[\mu \rho]}$ is already a genuine tensor, therefore I would say,  to construct a covariant derivative only  $\Gamma^\nu_{(\mu \rho)}$ as additional term to the usual partial derivative would be absolutely necessary.
By the way,  in extensions of General Relativity I have seen that -- in order to get rid of the torsion in the connection  which makes many formulas difficult ---   often the torsion part is kind of integrated out and one is left with a connection like in formula (2).

Torsion is not "absolutely necessary", as you point out, cf Hehl et al, 1976, so it's rarely considered.

FWIW, eq. (1) also holds for a torsionful connection by definition.

As definitions, they both work in the sense that both versions of the covariant derivative will transform as tensors. Whether you include the torsion tensor in the definition of covariant derivative is a choice.

@Prahar  Thank you for this information!
